# pybind11 realize a cpp middleware concept (basics)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

[CPP Middleware in a python enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peB4h.png)

I Want to realize this structure.

App (python) <-> Middleware (cpp) <-> Driver (python)

A App (python) will access some middleware classes in CPP. And then use a driver (python).

App.py

```
import pybind_11_example as middleware_cpp
n =  40
print('C++:')
print('Answer:', middleware_cpp.testFunctionA_cpp(n))
```

Middleware.h

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
class middleware 
{
    public:
    unsigned int testFunctionA(const unsigned int n);
    namespace py = pybind11;

    PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind_11_example, mod) {
    mod.def("testFunctionA_cpp", &testFunctionA, "Middleware class.");
}
```

Middleware.cpp

```
#include "Middleware.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>  // python interpreter
#include <pybind11/stl.h>  // type conversion

unsigned int middleware::testFunctionA(const unsigned int n)
{
    printf("Now Sent back to python driver interface\n");

    //py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start interpreter, dies when out of scope

    py::module driver= py::module::import("Driver");
    py::object result = driver.attr("setValue")("setting value from cpp to python driver");
    return 42;
}
```

Driver.py

```
class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Init Driver Class")
        self.name = "This is the Driver Class"

    def printMyClass(self):
        print(self.name)

    def setValue(self, value):
        print(value)
```

I have read the docs but did this example not working. So i want to place it here as a example template if other want also try this approach.

**Question 1:**

How do I call the python Driver class function "setValue" from cpp?

The current implementation from Middleware.cpp calling the function setValue leads to this error:

AttributeError: module 'Driver' has no attribute 'setValue'

**Question 2:**

Calling the interpreter twice should not be needed, because it is assumed, the the middleware is accessed from the running app process, which is already in python.

py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start interpreter, dies when out of scope

Best regards Holger

Comment: "not working" is a terrible diagnostic. Please edit your post with what you expected and what actually happens. Do you get a compile error? A crash? Nothing at all?

Comment: Also, did you really want to create a _new_ Python interpreter in the same process to run your driver code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have updated the my question above. THX